# Scale EPS and Change DPI Using Ghostscript

Tags: graphics, ghostscript, eps

I have a few EPS files that have an arbitrary size dimension (x/y) but are all 72 DPI.  I need to convert them to 600 DPI as well as scale the width to 3.25 inches.  I don't care what the height is, but I want to keep the aspect ratio the same.  Here's what I tried:

For my input image, I figured out the pixel dimension is 414x336.  I need to convert to 3.25 at 600 DPI.

3.25 * 600 = 1950

1950/(414/336) = 1583 (rounded up)

So I used ghostscript with the following parameters:

```
gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=epswrite -r600 -g1950x1583 -dEPSFitPage -sOutputFile=Figure_1_600.eps Figure_1.eps
```

This gives me an image with the appropriate dimensions (and aspect ratio) but it's still at 72 DPI when I want it to be 600 DPI.

```
identify -format "%w x %h %x x %y" Figure_1_600.eps 
235 x 190 72 Undefined x 72 Undefined
```

I feel like I'm missing something silly here... is it the order?  Can you not do both in the same statement?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Postscript uses 72 points per inch as measurement value for sizes, not as picture resolution. That doesn't mean you can't output it in 600 dpi when you rasterize it later: As EPS is a vector file format, you can scale it and get any resolution you like out of it.